# Reg exp for youtube link

Tags: php, regex, youtube, preg-match

In a system that I'm developing I need to recognize the youtube link in the following format

> [youtube]youtube url[/youtube]

for the moment I arrived at this regular expression:

```
#\[youtube\]http://www.youtube\.(.*)/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\[\/youtube\]#s
```

But this pattern isn't able to recognize url like

> [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3wXkv1VW54&feature=fvst[/youtube]

Note the **feature=fvst**.

Some one can help me in recognize all possible youtube url?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658763/php-regex-youtube, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php - see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube+regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
|\[youtube\]http://www.youtube\.(.*?)/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)[%&=#a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\[\/youtube\]|s
```

EDIT: Changed the regex to keep only the video id inside parentheses.

Comment: If two "youtube-links" are on the same line, the greedy `.*` will mess things up. I'd put a reluctant `?` after it, as Andy suggested (**edit:** who has now deleted his answer...).

Comment: No Tim, you failed: I saw you had a `.*` without a `?`! Guilty as charged! :) +1

Comment: Your pattern works but i like to directly match the video ID, with your pattern I have the entire query string.

Comment: @Bart: Misunderstanding there :) I meant that I saw Andy's answer in time before he removed it. I did only change my regex after your comment.

Comment: I deleted my answer because Tim pointed out that it wasn't quite the problem, and I didn't want to be hit by the downvote brigade.  It's bad enough getting downvoted when you give the correct answer ;-)

Comment: @Andy: True, it was not the answer to the question, but you had a point, hence my comment.

Comment: This SO answer provides an alternative : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12814235/363573

Answer (score 1):

Notes:
I'd perform a case-insensitive match on URLs (/i) 
. matches anything; use \. instead to match the URL
Also, "www." in Youtube URLs is optional. 
Use (\.[a-z]+){1,2} instead of ".*" to match ".com", ".co.uk", .. after "youtube"

Assuming the "&feature" part is optional, the regex would be:

`/\[youtube\]http:\/\/(www\.)?youtube(\.[a-z]+){1,2}\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9_-]*)(&feature=([a-z]+))?\[\/youtube\]/is`

Assuming the "&feature" part is optional, AND there can be other parameters than "feature":

```
/\[youtube\]http:\/\/(www\.)?youtube(\.[a-z]+){1,2}\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9_-]*)(&([a-z]+)=([a-z0-9_-])+)*?\[\/youtube\]/is
```