# Youtube I.D parsing for new URL formats

Tags: php, regex, youtube, format

This question has been asked before and I found this:

[Reg exp for youtube link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220764/reg-exp-for-youtube-link)

but I'm looking for something slightly different.

I need to match the Youtube I.D itself compatible with all the possible youtube link formats. Not exclusively beginning with youtube.com.

For example:

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wtIMTCHWuI`

`http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI?version=3&autohide=1`

`http://youtu.be/-wtIMTCHWuI`

`http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3D-wtIMTCHWuI&format=json`

`http://s.ytimg.com/yt/favicon-wtIMTCHWuI.ico`

`http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/-wtIMTCHWuI/hqdefault.jpg`

is there a clever strategy I can use to match the video I.D `-wtIMTCHWuI` compatible with all these formats. I'm thinking character counting and matching `=` `?` `/` `.` `&` characters.

Comment: Your method seems like the one I'd use. I'd probably find all the "splitting" characters in the URL like equals, slash, ampersand, Etc. The result would then be in an array. From there I'd loop through the array finding which strings were the same length as a YouTube ID. Id'd then run those through a regular expression to knock out all the strings with invalid characters. Finally, you could then use the YouTube API to check whether the video exists for that ID (would increase bandwidth though).

Comment: Not clever, but `/(\?v=|\/v\/|be\/|v%3d|favicon|vi\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/`

Comment: You may find [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string/5831191#5831191) helpful. (Although I've never seen the last two syntaxes in your question. (i.e. `http://s.ytimg.com` and `http://i2.ytimg.com`))

Comment: Thanks guys, all very helpful. I'm currently trying a combination of [parse_url](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) , stripping extraneous characters, and count.

Answer (score 50):

I had to deal with this for a PHP class I wrote a few weeks ago and ended up with a regex that matches any kind of strings: With or without URL scheme, with or without subdomain, youtube.com URL strings, youtu.be URL strings and dealing with all kind of parameter sorting. You can check it out [at GitHub](https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader/blob/master/youtube-dl.class.php#L400) or simply copy and paste the code block below:

```
/**
 *  Check if input string is a valid YouTube URL
 *  and try to extract the YouTube Video ID from it.
 *  @author  Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @param   $url   string   The string that shall be checked.
 *  @return  mixed           Returns YouTube Video ID, or (boolean) false.
 */
function parse_yturl($url)
{
    $pattern = '#^(?:https?://|//)?(?:www\.|m\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/(?:embed/|v/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))([\w-]{11})(?![\w-])#';
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```

Test cases: https://3v4l.org/GEDT0
JavaScript version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/624466

To explain the regex, here's a split up version:

```
/**
 *  Check if input string is a valid YouTube URL
 *  and try to extract the YouTube Video ID from it.
 *  @author  Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @param   $url   string   The string that shall be checked.
 *  @return  mixed           Returns YouTube Video ID, or (boolean) false.
 */
function parse_yturl($url)
{
    $pattern = '#^(?:https?://|//)?' # Optional URL scheme. Either http, or https, or protocol-relative.
             . '(?:www\.|m\.)?'      #  Optional www or m subdomain.
             . '(?:'                 #  Group host alternatives:
             .   'youtu\.be/'        #    Either youtu.be,
             .   '|youtube\.com/'    #    or youtube.com
             .     '(?:'             #    Group path alternatives:
             .       'embed/'        #      Either /embed/,
             .       '|v/'           #      or /v/,
             .       '|watch\?v='    #      or /watch?v=,
             .       '|watch\?.+&v=' #      or /watch?other_param&v=
             .     ')'               #    End path alternatives.
             . ')'                   #  End host alternatives.
             . '([\w-]{11})'         # 11 characters (Length of Youtube video ids).
             . '(?![\w-])#';         # Rejects if overlong id.
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but I recently became in need of this function but I have one question. How would you go about a URL with the m subdimain?

Comment: @Zach Just change `(?:www\.)?` to `(?:www|m\.)?`. See in action: http://3v4l.org/tDBAh

Comment: @eyecatchUp I think you mean `(?:www\.|m\.)?` instead of `(?:www\.)?`  Right?

Comment: Yep, of course. _(Bummer, can't edit a 2y old comment)_ Here's the working code: http://3v4l.org/vaq0i Thanks @rineez

Answer (score 3):

I found this code [this link](http://takien.com/864/php-how-to-parse-youtube-url-to-get-video-id-thumbnail-image-or-embed-code.php):

```
<?php 
/** 
 *  parse_youtube_url() PHP function 
 *  Author: takien 
 *  URL: http://takien.com 
 *  
 *  @param  string  $url    URL to be parsed, eg:  
 *                            http://youtu.be/zc0s358b3Ys,  
 *                            http://www.youtube.com/embed/zc0s358b3Ys
 *                            http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc0s358b3Ys 
 *  @param  string  $return what to return 
 *                            - embed, return embed code 
 *                            - thumb, return URL to thumbnail image
 *                            - hqthumb, return URL to high quality thumbnail image.
 *  @param  string     $width  width of embeded video, default 560
 *  @param  string  $height height of embeded video, default 349
 *  @param  string  $rel    whether embeded video to show related video after play or not.

 */  

 function parse_youtube_url($url,$return='embed',$width='',$height='',$rel=0){ 
    $urls = parse_url($url); 

    //expect url is http://youtu.be/abcd, where abcd is video iD
    if($urls['host'] == 'youtu.be'){  
        $id = ltrim($urls['path'],'/'); 
    } 
    //expect  url is http://www.youtube.com/embed/abcd 
    else if(strpos($urls['path'],'embed') == 1){  
        $id = end(explode('/',$urls['path'])); 
    } 
     //expect url is abcd only 
    else if(strpos($url,'/')===false){ 
        $id = $url; 
    } 
    //expect url is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcd 
    else{ 
        parse_str($urls['query']); 
        $id = $v; 
    } 
    //return embed iframe 
    if($return == 'embed'){ 
        return '<iframe width="'.($width?$width:560).'" height="'.($height?$height:349).'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id.'?rel='.$rel.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>'; 
    } 
    //return normal thumb 
    else if($return == 'thumb'){ 
        return 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'.$id.'/default.jpg'; 
    } 
    //return hqthumb 
    else if($return == 'hqthumb'){ 
        return 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'.$id.'/hqdefault.jpg'; 
    } 
    // else return id 
    else{ 
        return $id; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

I'm dealing with this too so if you find a better solution please let me know. It doesn't quite do what you need for images out of the box but it could be easily adapted.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but I wrote this regex today and it does not only identify the links but returns the video_id via match-group 6

```
^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)(\/)?(watch\?v=|\?v=)?(.*)$
```

https://gist.github.com/Shibizle/3c6707911ea716860786728d31f8e3e5

**Test it:** https://regex101.com/r/l0m7yh/1

**Picture:** [Regex YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V32hQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using this:

```
function _getYoutubeVideoId($url)
{
  $parts = parse_url($url);

  //For seriously malformed urls
  if ($parts === false) {
     return false;
  }

  switch ($parts['host']) {
     case 'youtu.be':
        return substr($parts['path'], 1);
        break;
     case 'youtube.com':
     case 'www.youtube.com':
        parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
        return $params['v'];
        break;
     default:
        return false;
        break;
  } 
}
```

It could be extended, but right now it works for most of the cases

Comment: I removed the prefixing visibility declaration `private` for the function. (Probably you copied that one from a class, but setting a visibility declaration for regular functions is invalid and reserved for class methods.)

Comment: @eyecatchUp: Yes, you're right, I copied it from a class. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what your looking for, but I found this great list of YouTube URLs ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486)).

Some of the URLs in the list are for proxy services and attribution links.  In my use case, the supplied string can either be a URL or just an ID - so a regex match wont do.

So, based on all of the possibilities here, the ID can be extracted with two regex replaces:

```
^.+(\/|vi?=|v%3D)
```

In all sampled cases this selects everything between the start of the string and the start of the ID.  Here is a demo [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4on30)

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-].+$
```

Additionally, in all sampled cases, this selects everything from the end of the ID (in the now truncated string) to the end of the string.
Here is a demo [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4on2t)