# regex to separate HTML GET parameters

Tags: regex, string, pcre, string-matching

How can I use a regular expression to separate `GET` parameters in a URI and extract a certain one? Specifically, I'm trying to get just the `v=` part of a YouTube watch URI. I've come up with `youtube.com\/watch\?(\w+=[\w-]+&?)*(v=[\w-]+)&?*(\w+=[\w-]+&?)*`, but that looks awfully repetitive. Is there a better (shorter?) way to do this?

Comment: “page parameters”—I'm not sure what these are called.

Comment: I think they are called POST parameters, or can reasonably be called that.

Comment: Actually, parameters in the url are `GET` parameters. If you submit a form, the resulting request most likely contains `POST` parameters with your input.

Comment: @Arjan Fixed again! Thanks. XD

Comment: Official name would be [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), by the way. You don't have to edit again - I'm sure everyone gets it `:)`

Comment: Next, please look at one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube+regex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reg exp for youtube link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220764/reg-exp-for-youtube-link)

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for correcting me - shows what I know about all this "web" stuff. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but none has *quite* what I wanted. I'm looking for something capable of pulling out *just* the video ID—regardless of whether it's first in the parameter list, last, or buried in between others. Nothing I've seen has worked quite like that yet.

For reference, I'm using [this web app](http://www.rubular.com) for testing, and this set of test URIs:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX&feature=results_video&playnext=1&list=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=XXXXXXXXXXX#!
http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_xxxxxx&feature=iv&src_vid=XXXXXXXXXXX&v=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Fellow Stack Exchangers, I propose the following regular expression to solve this:
`youtube.com\/watch\?(\S*)v=([\w-]+)`

Answer (score 0):

A simplified regex :

> ^(?:http://www.)?youtube.[^/]+?/watch?(.*?)(v=([^&]+))(.*)$